# Graphviz - how do I change rankdir in a subgraph within a subgraph?

Tags: cluster-computing, graphviz, ranking, dot, subgraph

I've got the following graph. I'm content with it, except for the nodes within the red rectangle:

[image]
(Here's the [Graphviz Visual Editor Link](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20fontname%3D%22Helvetica%2CArial%2Csans-serif%22%0D%0A%20%20fontsize%3D18%0D%0A%20%20rankdir%3D%22TB%22%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20node%20%5Bfontname%3D%22Helvetica%2CArial%2Csans-serif%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20edge%20%5Bfontname%3D%22Helvetica%2CArial%2Csans-serif%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20layout%3Ddot%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20rabbithole%20%5Blabel%3D%3C%3CFONT%20POINT-SIZE%3D%2230%22%3E%22rabbit%20hole%22%3C%2FFONT%3E%3E%20shape%3Drectangle%5D%0D%0A%20%20rabbit%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5C%22rabbit%5C%22%5Cn%28origin%20unknown%29%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20rabbithole%20-%3E%20rabbit%0D%0A%20%20rabbithole%20-%3E%20hole%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20hole%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5C%22hole%5C%22%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20hulaz%20%5Blabel%3D%3C%3CI%3E%3CFONT%20POINT-SIZE%3D%2220%22%3E%22hulaz%22%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FI%3E%3CBR%2F%3E%28PGmc%20root%2C%3CBR%2F%3E%22hollow%22%29%3E%2C%20shape%3Ddoublecircle%5D%0D%0A%20%20hollow%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5C%22hollow%5C%22%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20hohl%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5C%22hohl%5C%22%5Cn%28de%2C%20%5C%22hollow%5C%22%29%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20H%C3%B6hle%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5C%22H%C3%B6hle%5C%22%5Cn%28de%2C%20%5C%22cave%5C%22%29%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20hohl%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5C%22hohl%5C%22%5Cn%28de%2C%20%5C%22hollow%5C%22%29%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20hulahoop%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5C%22Hula%20Hoop%5C%22%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20holy%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5C%22holy%5C%22%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20hell%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5C%22hell%5C%22%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20hulaz%20-%3E%20hulahoop%20%5Bdir%3Dnone%20label%3D%22unrelated%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20hulaz%20-%3E%20holy%20%5Bdir%3Dnone%20label%3D%22unrelated%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20hulaz%20-%3E%20hell%20%5Bdir%3Dnone%20label%3D%22unrelated%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20subgraph%20cluster_hulaz%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20hole%20-%3E%20hulaz%20%5Bdir%3Dnone%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rank%3Dsame%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hulaz%20-%3E%20hollow%20%5Bdir%3Dnone%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hulaz%20-%3E%20hohl%20%5Bdir%3Dnone%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hollow%20-%3E%20hohl%20%5Bdir%3Dnone%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hohl%20-%3E%20H%C3%B6hle%20%5Bdir%3Dnone%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

I'd rather have the nodes "hollow" and "hohl" be atop each other, like so:
[image]
(Here's the [Graphviz Visual Editor Link](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20fontname%3D%22Helvetica%2CArial%2Csans-serif%22%0D%0A%20%20fontsize%3D18%0D%0A%20%20rankdir%3D%22LR%22%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20node%20%5Bfontname%3D%22Helvetica%2CArial%2Csans-serif%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20edge%20%5Bfontname%3D%22Helvetica%2CArial%2Csans-serif%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20layout%3Ddot%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20hulaz%20%5Blabel%3D%3C%3CI%3E%3CFONT%20POINT-SIZE%3D%2220%22%3E%22hulaz%22%3C%2FFONT%3E%3C%2FI%3E%3CBR%2F%3E%28PGmc%20root%2C%3CBR%2F%3E%22hollow%22%29%3E%2C%20shape%3Ddoublecircle%5D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20hollow%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5C%22hollow%5C%22%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20hohl%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5C%22hohl%5C%22%5Cn%28de%2C%20%5C%22hollow%5C%22%29%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20H%C3%B6hle%20%5Blabel%3D%22%5C%22H%C3%B6hle%5C%22%5Cn%28de%2C%20%5C%22cave%5C%22%29%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20hulaz%20-%3E%20hollow%20%5Bdir%3Dnone%5D%0D%0A%20%20hulaz%20-%3E%20hohl%20%5Bdir%3Dnone%5D%0D%0A%20%20subgraph%20cluster_f%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20penwidth%3D0%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20hollow%20-%3E%20hohl%20%5Bdir%3Dnone%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20hohl%20-%3E%20H%C3%B6hle%20%5Bdir%3Dnone%5D%0D%0A%7D)])

Every attempt at adding a nested subgraph was unsuccessful, despite using

- `newrank=true`,
- `compound=true`,
- `rank=same` and
- `rankdir="TB"`

Can anyone offer any advice?

Bonus question: I'd also prefer the "rabbit hole" node to be horizontically centered, but I haven't found out how to do that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Rearranged all the code to better understand it (made it easier for my eyes).
- Re-did ranking (**rank=same**)
- Used **minlen** to push bottom 3 nodes back to the bottom
- Used **group** attribute to encourage vertical alignment

p.s. **rankdir** applies to the entire (root) graph

```
digraph {
  fontname="Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"
  fontsize=18
  rankdir="TB"
  
  node [fontname="Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"]
  edge [fontname="Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"]
  layout=dot
  
  rabbithole [group=R label=<<FONT POINT-SIZE="30">"rabbit hole"</FONT>> shape=rectangle]
  rabbit     [label="\"rabbit\"\n(origin unknown)"]
  rabbithole -> rabbit
  rabbithole -> hole
  
  {rank=sink  // keep on same rank
    hulahoop [label="\"Hula Hoop\""]
    holy     [label="\"holy\""]
    hell     [label="\"hell\""]
  }
  
  hulaz -> hulahoop [minlen=2 dir=none label="unrelated"]  // push to bottom
  hulaz -> holy [dir=none label="unrelated"]
  hulaz -> hell [dir=none label="unrelated"]
   
  subgraph cluster_hulaz{
    hole [group=R label="\"hole\""]
  
    hulaz  [group=R label=<<I><FONT POINT-SIZE="20">"hulaz"</FONT></I><BR/>(PGmc root,<BR/>"hollow")>, shape=doublecircle]
    hollow [group=2 label="\"hollow\""]
    hohl   [group=2 label="\"hohl\"\n(de, \"hollow\")"]
    Höhle  [label="\"Höhle\"\n(de, \"cave\")"]
  
      { rank=same
      hole hollow
      }
      { rank=same
      hulaz  hohl Höhle
      }
      hole -> hulaz [dir=none]
      hulaz -> hollow [dir=none]
      hulaz -> hohl [dir=none]
      hollow -> hohl [dir=none]
      hohl -> Höhle [dir=none]
  }
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I learned a lot from your code and your reply. And it does what I had hoped for, of course 